# login/non-login and interactive/non-interactive shells

Tags: bash, shell

Are the concepts of login/non-login shells the same as the concepts of non-interactive/interactive shells (respectively)?

Or are the concepts orthogonal yielding four different combinations?

I am trying to get a clear picture of which `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` scripts get sourced under various circumstances and I find that articles sometimes use these concepts interchangeably.

Comment: Specifically focusing on which scripts are sourced makes this a worthwhile question.. could the title be edited?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

- **login** shell: A login shell logs you into the system as a specific user.  Necessary for this is a username and password. When you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to login into a virtual terminal you get after successful login: a login shell (that is interactive). Sourced files:

  - `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` for Bourne compatible shells (and `/etc/profile.d/*`)
  - `~/.bash_profile` for bash
  - `/etc/zprofile` and `~/.zprofile` for zsh
  - `/etc/csh.login` and `~/.login` for csh
- **non-login** shell: A shell that is executed without logging in. Necessary for this is a current logged in user. When you open a graphic terminal in gnome, it is a non-login (interactive) shell. Sourced files:

  - `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` for bash
- **interactive** shell: A shell (login or non-login) where you can interactively type or interrupt commands, for example, a gnome terminal (non-login) or a virtual terminal (login). In an interactive shell the prompt variable must be set (`$PS1`). Sourced files:

  - `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`
  - `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` for bash
- **non-interactive** shell: A (sub)shell that is probably run from an automated process.  You will see neither input nor output when the calling process doesn't handle it. That shell is normally a non-login shell, because the calling user has logged in already. A shell running a script is always a non-interactive shell, but the script can emulate an interactive shell by prompting the user to input values. Sourced files:

  - `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` for bash (but, mostly you see this at the beginning of the script: `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`. That means don't do anything if it's a non-interactive shell).
  - depending on shell; some of them read the file in the `$ENV` variable.

Comment: Nice explanation, but I still don't know why "That shell is normally a non-login shell, because the calling user has logged in already"?

Comment: Is there an easy way to add scripts to be run in non-interactive shells?

Comment: Nothing clean, but see https://superuser.com/q/1205681/81584

Comment: `[ -z "$PS1" ]` is an unsafe way of checking for interactive mode, because it could be part of the environment. `[[ $- != *i* ]]` is more secure.

Comment: @Bachsau "/etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc are also run in non-interative shells." -- I'm confused. `man bash` says `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` are only executed for **interactive** (non-login) shells. The comments in `/etc/bash.bashrc` (on Ubuntu 22.04) say the same.

Comment: @Bachsau Yeah, that's been confusing me, too. More generally, every source I've consulted seems to be saying something slightly different about when exactly .profile and .bashrc get sourced. Anyway, thanks for looking into this! I appreciate it!