# echo $PATH does not show added path in .bash_profile or /etc/profile

Tags: linux, bash, path

I have just installed LaTEX and need to add the path to my `$PATH` variable so I can use the command. I have tried adding path (`/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux`) to my `.bash_profile` and when I restart the terminal and `echo $PATH`, it does not show my addition.
The relevant code that I added:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux
export PATH
```

I have tried to add path to `/etc/profile` but without success. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, Eric and Cyrus, both of them are very useful. I rebooted the computer and now the path is added: success! Since the path is going to be read from now on (because at every login `.bash_profile` will be read), I take that it is not necessary anymore for me to add it to `.bashrc`, right?

Comment: Right, and as Giles pointed out, you probably shouldn't have put it there anyway, even though that's what i had recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. The location may or may not be correct. `.bash_profile` is read if your login shell is bash and you log in in text mode (on a text console or over the network). However, if you log in at a graphical prompt, on most systems, `.bash_profile` is not read, but `.profile` is. To avoid duplication, I recommend putting all environment variable assignments in `.profile` and using the following code for `.bash_profile` to do the right thing for both interactive and non-interactive login shells:

```
. ~/.profile
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

Don't put environment variable definitions such as `PATH` in `.bashrc`. This would only work in programs invoked from terminals, not e.g. if your editor attempts to run LaTeX automatically.

Since `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`) is only read when you log in, the setting won't take effect until you log out and back in. You can make the setting take effect in a terminal (including programs started from that terminal) by typing (or pasting) the `PATH=…` command there. Some desktop environments and window managers let you modify their environment variables; how to do this depends on the desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

`.bash_profile` is read only during a login, and opening a terminal is not a login.  You should probably ad this to your `.bashrc` instead so interactive shells will read it.

You can see some more discussion about this at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Gilles does not account for non-login interactive shell

---

## Summary:

If we need to add a PATH to both interactive and non-interative environment, we need to account for several cases:

1. **non-login interactive bash shell**

> Only read .bashrc, not .profile nor .bash_profile

2. **login interactive bash shell**

> Read .profile (and read .bashrc by default in .profile)
>
> or .bash_profile if exists

3. **login non-interactive shell**

> Read .profile only (or .bash_profile if exists)
>
> will not read .bashrc by default and the search for .bashrc in .profile shoudln't return true as below
>
> if [ -n '$BASH_VERSION']; then

4. **non-login non-interactive shell**

> Not reading anything by default

---

*note: my answer also might be not entirely correct, writing an answer over here just in case*

---

Source:

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells

   - not entirely correct, the wrong part is non-interactive shell doesn't invoke `.bashrc`
2. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

---

More:

1. [login/non-login and interactive/non-interactive shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170493/login-non-login-and-interactive-non-interactive-shells)

---

## Test for login non-interative case

To test for how .profile will run under login non-interative case, can add in some echo to files under if else statement

```
~/.profile

if [ -n '$BASH_VERSION'];
then
    echo test > test.txt
else
    echo bash version missing > test.txt
fi
```