# Bash isn't reading (source) .bashrc in AIX

Tags: bash, aix, bashrc

Why bash isn't reading the ~/.bashrc in AIX in non-interactive shells through ssh ? According to bash man page in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html it should do this:

> **Invoked by remote shell daemon**
>
> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard
> input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the
> remote shell daemon, usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd. ***If
> Bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes
> commands from ~/.bashrc***, if that file exists and is readable. It will
> not do this if invoked as sh. The --norc option may be used to inhibit
> this behavior, and the --rcfile option may be used to force another
> file to be read, but neither rshd nor sshd generally invoke the shell
> with those options or allow them to be specified.

Once running in AIX 7.1 it will be necessary also in AIX 5.1.

**AIX Version**: *uname -a*

> AIX p740 1 7 *????????????* powerpc AIX

**Bash version**: *bash --version*

> GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release
> (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation,
> Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
> http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
> ...

**Files snippets**: /etc/environment, /etc/profile, .bash_profile, and .bashrc

*/etc/environment*:

```
...
TESTGLOBAL="Defined in /etc/environment"
...
```

*/etc/profile*:

```bash
# First line
echo "Loading /etc/profile..."
...
```

*.bash_profile*:

```bash
# First line
echo "Loading .bash_profile..."
[ -e ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc
...
```

*.bashrc*:

```bash
# First line
echo "Loading .bashrc..."
export TESTLOCAL="Defined in ~/.bashrc"
...
```

**Remote shell is bash**: *But it doesn't read ~/.bashrc*

```
$ ssh -t user@localhost 'echo $SHELL, $0'
/bin/bash, bash
```

**Interactive shell:**

```bash
$ ssh user@localhost
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                                                                             *
*  Welcome to AIX Version 7.1!                                                *
*                                                                             *
*                                                                             *
*  Please see the README file in /usr/lpp/bos for information pertinent to    *
*  this release of the AIX Operating System.                                  *
*                                                                             *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************
Loading /etc/profile...
Loading .bash_profile...
Loading .bashrc...
$
$ set | grep TEST
TESTLOCAL='Defined in .bashrc'
TESTGLOBAL='"Defined in /etc/environment"'
```

**Remote commands**: *With or without -t flag*

```
$ ssh -t user@localhost 'echo $TESTLOCAL'

$ ssh -t user@localhost 'echo $TESTGLOBAL'
"Defined in /etc/environment"

$ ssh -t user@localhost 'set | grep TEST'
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING='set | grep TEST'
TESTGLOBAL='"Defined in /etc/environment"'
```

Comment: Pretty much normal default behaviour when passing commands to ssh.

Comment: `/etc/environment` is not a standard shell configuration file, but it is probably processed by some ancestor of `sshd`, which means the value of `TESTGLOBAL` is inherited by whatever process `ssh` ultimately runs. Its value is *not* set by any configuration file when `user` logs in.

Comment: No. This isn't the expected according to this, @RuiFRibeiro:  
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-speakingunix10/

Comment: /etc/environment isn't the question @chepner. This was included only to show some custom variable being set.

Comment: Luciano, that DW page is a little misleading in the 3rd paragraph of "Planning for the big Bash"; read further down where it talks about non-interactive shells

Comment: But it *isn't* set by the `ssh` command (or more precisely, by `sshd`). It was set long before, probably when the machine was booted, and was added to the environment of some command from which `sshd` finally inherited the value and passed it on to the environment of whatever command was requested by `ssh`.

Comment: @chepner, my intent was to ask about bash no reading .bashrc (although launched by ssh), it ins't working also with rsh, so it seems to be something with bash not ssh, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Non-interactive shells simply do not source `.bashrc`; it's the defined behavior of `bash`. An non-interactive shell will only source a file named by the `BASH_ENV` environment variable. (If run as `sh`, then it uses `ENV` instead to name a file to source.)

From the man page (bold is my emphasis)

> When  bash is invoked as an **interactive login shell**, or as a non-inter-
>          active shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  com-
>          mands  from  the file **/etc/profile**, if that file exists.  After reading
>          that file, it looks for **~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>          in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one** that
>          exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the
>          shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When  a  login  shell  exits, bash reads and executes commands from
>   the
>          file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> When an **interactive shell that is not a login shell**  is  started,  bash
>          reads  and executes commands from **~/.bashrc**, if that file exists.  This
>          may be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file  option
>          will  force  bash  to  read  and  execute commands from file instead of
>          ~/.bashrc.
>
> When bash is started **non-interactively**, to  run  a  shell  script,  for
>          example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands
>          its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the  name
>          of  a  file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following com-
>          mand were executed:
>                 if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
>          but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the  file-
>          name.

Comment: Can you give us more references that explains and ensures that bash in non-interactive shell doesn't read .bashrc ? That isn't what happen in Linux bash, and is spread over internet, like this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170499/114939

Comment: @Luciano see the "non-interactive shell" part of that answer -- no ~/.bashrc

Comment: Right, maybe a misunderstood in the header "Non-interactive" of my question (I fixed it), it seems to be interactive (non-login), `ssh -t user@localhost command` is "interactive non-login", it has a input attached by a network stream, so .bashrc should be read, but it isn't. According to "Invoked by remote shell daemon" in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Comment: No interactive shell is being run by `ssh`. Run `echo $-` in your current shell, and observe the `i` in the output (which means the current shell is an interactive shell). Now run `ssh localhost 'echo $-'`, and observe the absence of `i` in the output indicating it is *not* an interactive shell.

Comment: Maybe there are concept conflicts in the bash man pages, I prefer to not discuss the concept of interactive vs non-interactive. I need only the bash to read .bashrc when a command is remotely run by ssh or rsh. Like should do and is described in the bash man pages in the "Invoked by remote shell daemon" in http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html (in Linux it works, but in AIX no)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that only means in situations like `ssh user@localhost bash`, where it itself is the remote command to run, not when it is merely being used to execute the remote command. If it can detect that it is being run as a remote shell, it saves the user from having to specify the `-i` option to force it to run as an interactive shell.