# ssh command and non-interactive, non-login shell

Tags: shell, ssh, login, interactive

There is a sentence in the post below.
[Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856)

The focus is here:
Another way to get a non-interactive login shell is to log in remotely with a command passed through standard input which is not a terminal, e.g.
`ssh example.com <my-script-which-is-stored-locally` (as opposed to `ssh example.com my-script-which-is-on-the-remote-machine`, which runs a non-interactive, non-login shell).

The author arrives at two conclusions from the description above.

1. non-interactive login shell

   ```
    ssh example.com <my-script-which-is-stored-locally
   ```
2. non-interactive, non-login shell

   ```
    ssh example.com my-script-which-is-on-the-remote-machine
   ```

I don't think the second conclusion is right.
When to execute `ssh example.com my-script-which-is-on-the-remote-machine`, account name and password still be asked to input locally.
It is still a non-interactive login shell!

login shell: A login shell logs you into the system as a specified user, necessary for this is a username and password
According to  the web [description on login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170493/login-non-login-and-interactive-non-interactive-shells)

For the non-interactive non-login shell, give an example here: some daemon such as mysqld or apache2, all of them are non-interactive non-login shells.

It is your turn: true or false?

Comment: “logs you into the system as a spiecified user” is not a good definition of a login shell. Read my answer to understand what a login shell is.

Answer (score 3):

> When to execute ssh example.com my-script-which-is-on-the-remote-machine, account name and password still be asked to input locally.
>
> It is still a non-interactive login shell!

The interactivity of the login shell is not defined by the case "you enter login and password". You are prompted for the password by your local `ssh` (or the keys are used), it passes them to the remote `sshd` server and only if they are correctly verified, you are given a `shell` (unless you use `UseLogin yes` in the `sshd_config`, which is quite dangerous).

Answer (score 3):

The login is the core concept in jargon--login shell.
There are four stages abstracted to describe linux work:Init, Getty, Login , Shell.
Here login is a program, which gets the username as a parameter, and prompts the user for the password.
On local side:

```
vim   /tmp/shell.sh   
shopt login_shell
```

On server side(my vps server):

```
vim   /tmp/shell.sh   
shopt login_shell
```

1.non-interactive login shell
general format:    **`ssh example.com <my-script-which-is-stored-locally`**

```
ssh  root@vps_ip  < /tmp/shell.sh
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
login_shell     on
```

More clearly

```
ssh -t -t root@vps_ip  < /tmp/shell.sh
Last login: Wed Mar  8 03:16:00 2017 from vps_ip
root@localhost:~$ 
root@localhost:~$ shopt login_shell 
login_shell     on
```

The interpreter on local side break **`ssh -t -t root@vps_ip  < /tmp/shell.sh`** into two parts.
1.ssh -t -t root@vps_ip
login program accept root as user on the vps,logined.
2./tmp/shell.sh
the script on the local side passed as a parameter into interpreter on remote side ,and executed.

It is non-interactive login shell  during the process.

2.non-interactive non-login shell
general format:**ssh example.com my-script-which-is-stored-on-remote-machine**

```
debian8@hwy:~$ssh   root@vps_ip  '/bin/bash /tmp/shell.sh'
login_shell     off
debian8@hwy:~$
```

It is non-interactive non-login shell  during the process.

Some hack trick can make it display as login shell.

```
debian8@hwy:~$ssh   root@vps_ip  '/bin/bash --login /tmp/shell.sh'
login_shell     on
debian8@hwy:~$
```

The vps server does not be logined after the whole command **ssh   root@vps_ip  '/bin/bash --login /tmp/shell.sh'** performed.
The **login_shell on** displayed no meaning,it logined but vps server closed connection ,logined out.
Gilles's conclusions on  [non-interactive login shell and non-interactive non-login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856) is right.

Comment: I accidentally added a `source` statement to my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file that contained an `exit 0` command at the end of the script sourced every time when accessing the server.
`ssh -t -t root@vps_ip  < /tmp/shell.sh`
This command saved my ass, thank you.