# Confused about the meaning of an interactive and non-interactive shell when running a script

Tags: linux, shell, interactive

I have read the following in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170493/login-non-login-and-interactive-non-interactive-shells?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> A shell running a script is always a non-interactive shell, but the
>   script can emulate an interactive shell by prompting the user to input
>   values.

I don't know if the above statement is correct, I thought the following is correct:

- A shell running a script and this script allows you to input data is an interactive shell (and not an "emulation" of an interactive shell like the quote says).
- A shell running a script and this script does not allow you to input data is a non-interactive shell.

Which statement is correct?

Comment: Interactivity of a shell has to do with how said shell was started, not with how you enter data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell running a script is a non-interactive shell.

A non-interactive shell can still use e.g. `read` to read data from standard input.

If standard input is a terminal, this may provide a level of "interaction", but it does not make the shell executing the script an interactive shell. Thu *script* will be "interactive" though.

The text is confusing because it uses the word "interactive" to mean two things:

1. A shell that was started in order to execute a shell script is non-interactive (in the sense that it does not have job control, it does not provide a prompt by itself by default etc. etc.).  This is a technical term for the type of a shell, just like "login shell" and "interactive shell".
2. The action of acquiring data by this same script may be "interactive" (if not reading from e.g. a pipe or a file). But then again, any command that takes data from standard input may be said to be interactive.  `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'` will, by itself, "interactively" turn all lowercase ASCII characters to uppercase.

Comment: If I opened Terminal and Terminal is using the `bash` shell, now I am using an interactive shell. Now say I executed a script using the same `bash` shell that Terminal is using, while the script is being executed, do we say that `bash` has become a non-interactive shell, or is it the script itself that is a non-interactive shell?

Comment: @Tom No. The interactive shell is giving over control to a non-interactive shell. You are now dealing with two shells (two shell processes). Both are `bash` shells, but one is interactive (the one you started the script from, which is now waiting for the script to finish), and one is non-interactive (the one running the script).

Comment: You are right, I tested executing a script and a new `bash` process was created. So basically a shell that executes a script is called non-interactive because I really can't send anything to the shell (when the script is using `read` and I send some text from the terminal, it is the script that will eventually handle this string and not the shell), correct?

Comment: @Tom I would say that this is a correct understanding, yes. Mostly. It is correct enough. :-)