# Which file is loaded and executed by a non-interactive non-login shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, interactive

A non-login interactive shell (for example: when I open a Terminal window in Ubuntu) loads and executes the file `~/.bashrc`.

Now when I execute a shell script, a non-interactive non-login shell process will be created that will run this shell script.

Is there a file that is loaded and executed by this non-interactive non-login shell?

---

**Edit:** The shell I am using is `bash`.

Comment: How *exactly* do you execute that shell script? It could matter...

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I am executing the shell script from the Terminal window (`./my_shell_script.sh`).

Comment: A nice description of [files sourced](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170499/232326)

Answer (score 3):

From `man bash`, in a *non-interactive* shell the `BASH_ENV` environment variable is evaluated and its content is sourced. So you could use that environment variable to specify a file with your environment settings.
By default no files will be sourced in *non-interactive* mode.

```
When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV
in  the  environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file 
to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
       if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the filename.
```

Answer (score 2):

When you execute some shell script with a non-interactive non-login shell, notably by using [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) in some C program (or by running it from [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)), no file is implicitly loaded.

Your script might source some file, using `.` or [`source` shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).

Perhaps you should care about which environment (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)) or what [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) are relevant, and that depends on how your shell script is started, what are the ancestor processes, etc. If you run your script from a shell in a terminal window, it inherits many things from your shell (notably your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))). However, if you run that script differently (in some init or systemd script, thru `cron` or `batch` or `nohup`, ....) things can be different.

See also [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html), [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) ....

Read [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (both are used in your shell), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

Read chapter on [Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).